# Writing a Subscriber in Python

Tags: rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I am trying to write a subscriber program in ROS fuerte with python and I get this error after I type "rosmake  packagename" to build my package.
I have "import rospy " in the python code but still I get some errors.
The error I get is CMake cannot determine linker language for target(then it appears the name of python program)

I am following the ros tutorials and as far as my knowledge I have considered all steps necasary for writing a subscriber.

Can you please help me with my issue?

Here is the code for CMake.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.4.6)
include($ENV{ROS_ROOT}/core/rosbuild/rosbuild.cmake)
rosbuild_init()
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)
rosbuild_add_executable(WhichFace src/WhichFace.py)
```

and here is the code for Manifest.xml

```
 <package>
  <description brief="finalPhone">finalPhone  </description>
  <author>pi</author>
  <license>BSD</license>
  <review status="unreviewed" notes=""/>
  <url>http://ros.org/wiki/finalPhone</url>
  <depend package="std_msgs"/>
  <depend package="rospy"/>
</package>
```

Thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/212865/writing-a-subscriber-in-python/) by [Sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/21550/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2015-07-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) on 2015-07-03**:
what's the steps you did? The information is not enough to debug.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-07-04**:
Please the contents of your `CMakeLists.txt` and `package.xml`. You are most likely treating a Python program as a C++ program (ie: trying to link it against other libraries). Python nodes do not need to be linked against anything.

**Comment by [Sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/21550/sam/) on 2015-07-05**:
Sure.This is manifest.xml

```
 finalPhone
```

pi
  BSD
  
  http://ros.org/wiki/finalPhone

**Comment by [Sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/21550/sam/) on 2015-07-05**:
And this is my Cmakelist.txt:

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.4.6)
include($ENV{ROS_ROOT}/core/rosbuild/rosbuild.cmake)
rosbuild_init()
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
rosbuild_add_executable(WhichFace src/WhichFace.py)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-07-06**:
Can you add this (properly formatted) to your original question? Please use the `edit` button/link for that (to the right of *Comments* under your question), and use the *Preformatted Text* button to format the manifest and build script.

**Comment by [Sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/21550/sam/) on 2015-07-06**:
Sure.I did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Here is the code for CMake.txt:

> ```
> cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.4.6)
> ```

```
include($ENV{ROS_ROOT}/core/rosbuild/rosbuild.cmake)
rosbuild_init()
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)
rosbuild_add_executable(WhichFace src/WhichFace.py)
```

Python nodes are not 'executables' in the sense that you can `rosmake` them. You cannot `rosbuild_add_executable(..)` as that will cause CMake (underlying `rosbuild`) to try and setup all sorts of make targets for building and *linking* the Python script *as if it were a C/C++ program*. That is obviously not the case, so it fails.

See [wiki/rospy_tutorials/Tutorials/Makefile](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy_tutorials/Tutorials/Makefile) (make sure to switch to *rosbuild* at the top of the page) for how to setup a `CMakeLists.txt` for Python nodes under `rosbuild`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-07-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1